# How to make a multi node ethereum private network

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain

I'm trying to build a private network that is composed of 2 nodes. Each of the 2 nodes have to deploy a smart contract and to transact the other contract.

The problem is that I'm confused about the best way and the best or easy tools to buils such network?(geth, ganache,...)

my question is: 
can any one guide me to choose the best and easy tools to do this or is there a good tutorial to follow?

Answer (score 1):

there is an official guidance on Ethereum project's wiki: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Private-network